# AKPanner node not affecting output

Tags: swift, audio, audiokit

I've been struggling with this for a while now.

I've got an array of AKPlayers.

```
var players = [AKPlayer]()
```

Then I create an AKPanner node, set the pan, and connect it into the input of an AKMixer

```
let playerNode = AKPlayer(audioFile: c.audioFile!)
playerNode.pan = 0

var pannerNode = AKPanner(playerNode, pan: 1)
self.audioMixer.connect(input: pannerNode)

players.append(playerNode)
panners.append(pannerNode)
```

I also throw the nodes into an array due to [this](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/issues/784)

Then I do the following:

```
do {
   AudioKit.output = audioMixer
   try AudioKit.start()
} catch {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I am able to hear sound, but it is in both ears. Not in my right ear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So, you're setting the player pan to the left and setting a panner to the right and its coming out both?  That's weird. Curious: why are you using a panner instead of using AKPlayer pan? Any chance you could share a project demonstratin the issue?

Comment: Hey Aurelius. Thanks for responding. Before starting with the approach of using AKPanner, I tried just using the pan option of AKPlayer, but the same result occurred. On another note, playerNode.pan = 0 means both, not left. Left would be -1. Yet, that should not matter due to the AKPanner node. I'll see if I can get an example project up and running.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, that is the correct behavior for the pan numbers you gave, my mistake. Sorry! Thanks for trying to put an example together. Alternatively, we could do a screenshare.

Comment: Either way would be great Aurelius. Is there an email I could contact you at?

Comment: Thank you Aurelius for making me make an example. That was a huge step to finding out the solution.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it wasn't something wrong with AudioKit after all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was not with the code at all, but rather, with a setting on my phone.

Make sure that `Mono Audio` is turned **off** in the iOS settings under:

```
General > Accessibility > Mono Audio
```

**Note: `Mono Audio` is under the `Hearing` section